# Execute Consumers in a row

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a couple of `Consumer<MyObject>` classes I want to execute in sequence. I know I can do this with `myConsumer1.andThen(myConsumer2).accept(myvalue)`. How can I do this if I have a `List<Consumer<MyObject>>` and the number of consumers is unknown?

Here is a for-loop solution that I think is not concise:

```java
Consumer<MyObject> result;
for (Consumer<MyObject> consumer : consumers) {
    if(result == null) {
        result = consumer;
    } else {
        result.andThen(consumer);
    }
}
result.apply(myvalue);
```

Comment: Use a for loop.

Comment: `consumers.forEach(c -> c.accept(myvalue));` would do it. No streams, loop is tucked away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the list and apply each consumer to myValue.

```java
for (Consumer<MyObject> consumer : consumerList) {
    consumer.accept(myValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `Stream::reduce` to build a composed `Consumer`:

```java
consumerList.stream()
    .reduce(Consumer::andThen)
    .ifPresent(consumer -> consumer.accept(myValue));
```

Comment: Note the composition here only guarantees that they are executed in-sequence, accepting the value one after the other. Realistically not seeing a benefit over a simple loop for immediate execution, but I do see benefit if you're trying to pass that `Consumer` along to something else. In which case, `.orElse(() -> () -> {});` (a little nutty, but an empty consumer decl) in order to pass it along.